# CSS translate animation blurry for skewed text with opacity < 1

Tags: html, css, sass, css-animations

I know there are a lot of topics covering blur caused by CSS animations, but I seem to have come across a rather unique use case where every solution I've come across simply doesn't work.

I made a codepen showing a minimalist setup of my exact issue:

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/ericgrosse/pen/YqZGYp)

Basically, I have a `div` with opacity `0.95` that is skewed by 10 degrees, and whose inner content is skewed by -10 degrees (so that it appears upright). Within this content there is a paragraph at the bottom. When you hover over it, it triggers an animation of the paragraph being shifted to the right. Unfortunately this makes all the text on the page blur.

Note that removing either both skew transformations or the opacity setting make the text not blur anymore.

Comment: Since you already know that removing the opacity setting fixes the bug... why don't you remove it? Choose between `opactiy:.95` and the blur bug and `opacity: 1` with no blur bug. What will it be?

Comment: I wouldn't be posting this question unless I wanted both properties.

Comment: I can't give a complete answer (nor a 100% authoritative explanation) but it seems to be because of accelerated rendering and layer creation in browsers. For Chrome, `.jumbotron *{backface-visibility: hidden;}` fixes the issue perfectly but that still does nothing in IE11 and Firefox.

Comment: Questions asking to debug code need to contain an [MCVE] **in the question**.  Unless you have a Sass->CSS compilation issue, **only provide the compiled CSS** (and the necessary HTML to reproduce the problem).

Comment: How is that not provided in the codepen? There's an option in the SCSS pane to "View Compiled" and the html is provided in the left pane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably caused by the `skew` and the reverse `skew` that force the browser to accelerate the process. But you don't have to apply two `skews` to get this result, you can also use a `gradient background`

```
background:linear-gradient(170deg, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 164px, #a3d5d3 163px, #a3d5d3 calc(100% - 165px), rgba(0,0,0,0) calc(100% - 165px), rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
```

Comment: Thanks, did not know you could do angled gradients